# Zend Studio 9 Settings Export / Import

Tags: zend-studio

Simple question:

Is there a way to export / import settings to a new install in Zend Studio 9. The main required aspect being to recreate my code colouring set-up.

I cannot see anything related in the Export menu and copying from hidden application data in the past did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not shure if I understand you right. In "File" you have "Import" and "Export" funcionalities. Then just select "General" > "Preferences" to export your settings. This worked for me.

[image: Zend Studio preferences export]

Comment: Well, I use my own syntax colors for PHP, and this export/import works like a charm.

Comment: That does actually work now (despite not showing the PHP editor settings in the export dialogue after your screengrab). Must have been fixed in an update (an old profile file I have still does not work). Thanks.

Comment: It's work, not perfectly on zend IDE 13, but this is a start, thanks !